# How to specify the step in sum?

Tags: math-mode

The traditional sum's step is 1, but what if I want to specify the step to be some integer else?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) answers is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a notational question rather than a TeX one (thus not really on topic for this site) but the `\sum` nottaion is used to sum over a set or over an implied list indexed by a range of integers so if you want to sum for example every second item in a list x_i then you just double i when referencing

```
\sum_{i=1}^n x_{2i}
```